# Не работает NAT через GRE туннель

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, debian, pfsense

На сервере 1 установлен pfsense. На 2ом сервере установлен debian.
Так создал GRE туннель:

GRE pfsense настройки:

> [image: GRE pfsense настройки]

Введённые команды на 2ом сервере:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Туннель работает:

> [image: Тык 1]

и

> [image: Тык 2]

Почему правило NAT не работает?(все порты работают, фильтр перезагружен)

> [image: картинка]

ИП соединения передаваться должен
P.S жду обновления ответа от eri

Comment: где настройки нат?

Comment: @eri какие настройка nat?

Comment: все) но похоже типичная проблема. ответ ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего тут проблема с [марсианами](https://www.google.ru/search?q=martian%20packets).

Так как пфсенс не является шлюзом по умолчанию для дебиана - дебиан пытается ответить напрямую. Клиент получает ответ от адреса который не запрашивал.

Эта проблема решается добавлением правила src-nat на gre туннель со стороны pfsensa. Дебиан в этом случае отвечает пфсенсу, а тот отпрвляет ответ клиенту.

Правило в pfsense называется Outbound NAT. Нужен маскарад или SNAT на айпишник gre тунеля.

Со стороны дебиана это можно исправить через маркировку соединений и полиси роутинг (в разы сложнее).

Как-то так. Возможно прийдется доработать.

```
# один раз
echo 101 tunnelgre0 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# в скрипты
PEERIP=10.0.2.1
LOCALIP=10.0.1.1

ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \
  remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0 ttl 64

ip addr add $LOCALIP peer $PEERIP dev gre0
ip link set gre0 up

ip route add default via $PEERIP table tunnelgre0
# ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via $PEERIP # локальная сеть за пфсенсом, можно добавить так, но в случае если с пфсенс проброс - мало поможет.

ip rule add from $LOCALIP table tunnelgre0 # на этом месте уже заработает часть сервисов

ip rule add fwmark 20 table tunnelgre0
# ip rule add from $LOCALIP fwmark 20 table tunnelgre0 # или так


iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d $LOCALIP -j MARK --set-mark 20
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d $LOCALIP -j CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

Comment: и как добавить  src-nat?

Comment: Outbound NAT настраивается в разделе Firewall > NAT на вкладке Outbound .

Comment: @Cus под рукой нет пфсенса... посмотри в доках. буду на днях ставить его - скриншотну как должно выглядеть.

Comment: так https://prnt.sc/o3yb8a ?

Comment: и я добавил только gre туннель и других настроек iptables, sysctl -w  не делал

Comment: @Cus почти все не так.

Comment: @Cus интерфейс гре. Потом интерфейс адрес оставляешь. Порт убери

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95169/discussion-between-cus-and-eri).

Comment: вы про меня не забыли?)

Comment: @Cus. помню, но некогда было стенд собирать) накидал примерно, попробуй. может доработать прийдется

Comment: теперь с некоторых ип коннект идёт, а с других получаю timeout
https://prnt.sc/o89nzl

Comment: если включаю правило в outbound - http://prntscr.com/o89ose

Comment: проверил через "Diagnostics/Packet Capture" и на некоторых ип исходящие пакеты просто не идут

Comment: Что значит исходящие? Откуда они исходят?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EKgxVf3t